# How to find specific string, with certain starting and ending character in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

how to find all the strings which starts with open square bracket and ends with close square bracket in text file.
**used below code but getting some unwanted contents** also. How to avoid those unwanted contents

```
Select-String -Path "text.txt" -Pattern '\['
```

**input file**:
some conents **[hello]** 
adfhjadf adfjkkf **[ghad]** 
**[check]** dfgsf sfgfs

**required output file**
[hello]
[ghad]
[check]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
$string = @'
some conents [hello]
adfhjadf adfjkkf [ghad]
[check] dfgsf sfgfs
'@

([regex]'\[.*?\]').Matches($string)
```

Note, this will match anything inside the brackets. If you're looking only for English characters you should refine the regex.

Output should look like this:

```
Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 13
Length   : 7
Value    : [hello]

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 39
Length   : 6
Value    : [ghad]

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 47
Length   : 7
Value    : [check]
```

If you just want to see the matches you can do:

```
PS /> ([regex]'\[.*?\]').Matches($string).Value

[hello]
[ghad]
[check]
```

Comment: no luck bro... check this below image
https://pasteboard.co/K3orBbv.png

Comment: working fine thanks bro.... if i asked worthy question then just click upvote bro :)